# How to avoid indented nested promises?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I heard that promises are supposed to be linear in code in opposed to callbacks ("callback hell").

Though I still have a scenario similar to callback hell and hoping promises can make their promise and have a linear syntax equivalent to this problem code.

Given promises `p()`, `q()`,`w()` consider this code:

```
p().then(() => {
    q().then(() => {
       w().then(() => {
           // do something
       })
    })
})
```

Can we make an equivalent code which is not indented for every nested promise?

Comment: If the subsequent promises rely on the preceding promises, they have to indent.  Otherwise look into using `async/await` to change your styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not nest the `.then()` handlers but let each `.then()` create and return a new [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This is how it was designed to work, otherwise you are still in the callback hell, now the version with promises. No big difference.

The code should be like this:

```js
p()
  .then(() => {
    return q();
  })
  .then(() => {
    return w();
  })
  .then(() => {
    // do something
  });
```

If all that the `.then()` handlers do is to call the next function you can write it in a simpler form (read about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions)):

```js
p()
  .then(() => q())
  .then(() => w())
  .then(() => {
    // do something
  });
```

Even more, if `q` and `w` are called without arguments, the code could be as simple as:

```js
p()
  .then(q)
  .then(w)
  .then(() => {
    // do something
  });
```

Or you can go the extra mile and instead of using [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) you use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). The code becomes even more clear and easy to read:

```js
try {
  await p();
  await q();
  await w();
  // do something
} catch (err) {
  // write here the code you would write in the handler you pass to `.catch()
  // in the approach that uses Promises
}
```

### Remarks

If the code above, using `await`, is used in a function then that function must be an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (just put `async` in front of its definition).

The code that uses `await` [may or may not be used outside of a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Browser_compatibility) (i.e. at module's top level) depending on the runtime you use to run it (browser, Node.js etc).

Answer (score 3):

As another user mentioned, you could use `async/await` but another option is just to slightly restructure what you have. Here are some examples of what could work – depending on where and when you need certain pieces of data:

```
p()
  .then(q)
  .then(w)

// OR

p()
  .then(() => q())
  .then(() => w())
```

Obviously this gets a little more complicated if `w()` needs data from both `p()` and `q()` but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `async/await`, which leaves a more cleaner code. It would be like this:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        await p();
        await q();
        await w();
    } catch (e) {
        // handle error
    }
})()
```

If there is no dependency between each promise you can use `await Promise.all` in order to do "all or nothing". In any other case, you can store the returned value and pass it to the next function in order to be used if needed.