# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when using JWT token and refresh token

Tags: node.js, jwt, refresh-token

Sorry I'm new to backend (nodejs) and I'm trying to build a JWT token and refresh token but I stumbled across an error that I cannot fix when I try to run an endpoint in insomnia.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

This is the code snippet from the area the error came from in my app.js file

```
app.post('/users/login', (req, res) => {
   let email = req.body.email;
   let password = req.body.password;

   User.findByCredentials(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
         return user.createSession()
            .then((refreshToken) => {
               return user.generateAccessAuthToken()
               .then((accessToken) => {
                  return { accessToken, refreshToken };
               });
            })
            .then((authTokens) => {
               res
                  .header('x-refresh-token', authTokens.refreshToken)
                  .header('x-access-token', authTokens.accessToken)
                  .send(user);
            })
   }).catch((e) => {
      res.status(400).send(e);
   });
});
```

And this is the code for the method "findByCredentials" in my user.model.js file

```
UserSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function(email, password) {
    let User = this;
    User.findOne({ email }).then((user) => {
        if(!user) return Promise.reject();

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
                if (res) resolve(user);
                else {
                    reject();
                }
            })
        })
    });
}
```

Please help me

Error solved: I just needed to return the value of the findByCredentials method to solve the problem

Comment: We need to figure out *which* "then" is the problem.  SUGGESTION: [You should not nest the .then() handlers but let each .then() create and return a new Promise. This is how it was designed to work, otherwise you are still in the callback hell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65514754/421195)

Comment: ```User.findByCredentials(email, password)
      .then``` The first .then is the problem according to the console

Comment: Kotai - so you're going to follow everyone's advice and refactor your code to eliminate the "nested thens", right?

Comment: Alright I'd try it out and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Cool - great!  ALSO: "User" is undefined inside your app.post() method.  Hence the crash.  You haven't really shown us where/how it's initialized.  Javascript doesn't really have the equivalent of "global static variables"; Javascript "variable scope" rules are very different from other languages.  Here's a good article: [Variable Scope in Modern JavaScript](https://andy-carter.com/blog/variable-scope-in-modern-javascript)

Comment: I just looked through the second code snippet I posted and noticed that the reason it was returning an undefined value was because I wasn't returning anything. I just had to return User.findOne and it started working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since the error isn't posted, it's hard to pinpoint the error line & cause.
But I would suggest using .catch blocks along with the end of every .then chain and get the spot/line of error

**Recommendation:**
You are creating a callback hell by using nested .then chains [what is call back hell](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-callback-hell-in-node-js/).
Try using async/await syntax to achieve the same functionality in a simplified way - [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Regards,
Muhamed

Comment: ```User.findByCredentials(email, password)
      .then``` The first .then is the issue according to the console

Comment: Can you check the initialization or referencing of the mongoose schema model before calling its static function?  
Ref: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics  
Eg: const Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);

Comment: I figured it out. I wasn't returning the first statement of the findByCredentials method. It has started working. Thank you

Comment: Congratulations, if your issue is sorted out and my answer help is useful mark my instruction as useful and close this thread or kindly update your answer and mark this thread as closed.

Answer (score 0):

As if you didn't send any code snippet, it is quite clear. But after going through your code it seems after resolving the "user" you are calling two methods createSession and generateAccessAuthToken. And as you also didn't send any code snippet of these methods I'm assuming you are having error from one of the functions.

**And a piece of advice:**

- Practice best error handling patterns. It will help you in your journey.
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFTFtuEQ-10
- And async js:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoRJizFvM7s

Comment: ```User.findByCredentials(email, password)
      .then``` The console tells me the error is coming from the first .then